# How to disable/remove the chrome headless disclaimer in selenium and java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome-headless

I have automated a page and running through 'Chromeheadless', Script is in an infinite loop because there is a chrome automation disclaimer and under that, the actual element to click exists.

The automation page is attached below:
[image]

The Automation code to make chrome as headless is as below:

```
String chromePath = getChromeDriverPath();
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromePath);
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1200","--ignore-certificate-errors");
            options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
             driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

If I run the script using a normal chrome driver, it is working fine. The issue with only chrome headless mode. Please help me how to disable/remove the disclaimer to proceed with the execution.

Comment: You have to make sure that your chrome driver version is compatible with your chrome browser version.

Comment: Thanks munge for your reply, it is working fine with normal mode. only headless mode getting the notification. My Chrome browser and driver both are versions 84

Comment: What's your selenium version? What's value has `chromePath `?

Comment: Are you using Google Chrome or Chromium browser?

Comment: Hi @pburgr, I am using the selenium 3.141.59 version. in Chromepath, I have the chrome driver location and get that and set the system property.

Comment: Hi @munge, I am using Google Chrome browser.