# Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally .(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) in java

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Hello I use selenium on ubuntu with java, I create a user for glassfish and run glassfish on it, The selenium version and chrome I use for chrome 115, But when I start selenium the errors shows :

```
"Unknown Computer","127.0.1.1","Linux 5.4.0-155-generic, architecture: amd64-64","glassfishuser","Cbc","0.1.0 nightly","Java version 17.0.8",FATAL,41395277,2023-08-10 10:42:22.771 IRST,ir.mehritco.megnatis.cbc.CbcRobot.<init>(CbcRobot.java:49),"We have problem with instance chrome Driver : Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
Host info: host: 'srv2851084109', ip: '127.0.1.1'
Build info: version: '4.11.0', revision: '040bc5406b'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-155-generic', java.version: '17.0.8'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*, --user-data-dir=/home/glass..., user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Win..., --lang=en-GB, --disable-dev-shm-usage, --ignore-certificate-errors, --disable-gpu, start-maximized, --no-sandbox, disable-infobars, --disable-extensions, --enable-sandbox], excludeSwitches: [enable-automation], extensions: [], useAutomationExtension: false}}]}]",,,"",,"",
"Unknown Computer","127.0.1.1","Linux 5.4.0-155-generic, architecture: amd64-64","glassfishuser","Cbc","0.1.0 nightly","Java version 17.0.8",INFO,41395278,2023-08-10 10:42:22.772
```

The chrome Present at the location : /opt/google/chrome/chrome
and work if excute in terminal.
This is log from my log server. and the Option for Selenium is :

```
    public final ChromeDriver headless(String profileLocation) {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=" + profileLocation);//#e.g. C:\Users\You\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
        options.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        options.addArguments(userAgent[1]);
        options.addArguments("--lang=en-GB");
        options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
        options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63649026/how-to-disable-remove-the-chrome-headless-disclaimer-in-selenium-and-java
        options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
        //https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/headless-is-going-away/
//        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
//        options.addArguments("--window-size=1400,800");
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");


        options.addArguments("--enable-sandbox");
        return new ChromeDriver(options);
    }
```

And The headless mode is off (headless==false).
but the error keep goes and all application fails to run.

I added the chrome driver from System property.

`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);`

Comment: How do you get chromedriver ?